# this domain is already in use error?

Tags: ftp, web, wordpress, web-hosting

I purchased a domain from Godaddy.com and hosted it using 000webhost.com free of cost. Now i have forgotten the credentials of my 000webhost.com and i want to host it on again on same site.

Now I created a new account on 000webhost.com and trying to host it. now when i try to parkdomain- it says domain is already in use.

i have updated the DNS with new DNS also, do i need to do some other changes also. I tried on other hosting site also. but there it shows some other error.

Need help thanks.

Comment: How long ago did you do it? Sometimes the DNS can take a bit to successfully propagate all the way. I would wait a bit then try again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have forgotten your 000webhost.com password, you can reset your password [here](https://www.000webhost.com/password-reset/user).

You should regain access to your old account rather than create a new one because you have already setup your domain under the old account. That's most likely the reason you're getting an error when you try to add your domain to the new account.

Comment: This. It is silly to create new accounts just because you lost your password unless you used false information when creating the account and have absolutely no access to the account and no way to reclaim it.